# Html table on Html page - NO XML

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, html-table, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to grab data from an Html table on a website. No XML is involved.

```
<table id="e-cal-table" class="e-cal-table" width="100%">

<tr>

    <th>Date</th>

    <th>Time</th>

    <th>Currency</th>

    <th>Event</th>

    <th>Importance</th>

    <th>Actual</th>

    <th>Forecast</th>

    <th>Previous</th>

    <th>Notes</th>

</tr>
```

The following results in "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("http://www.example.com");

string table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='e-cal-table']").InnerText;
```

I'm at a loss as to how to identify the table for future parsing. Unfortunately, the only examples I've been able to find have to do with XML.

Comment: Why are you getting `InnerText` instead of `InnerHtml`?

Comment: `InnertText` will probably give you nothing. The table has no text nodes. You may want to try `InnerHtml`.

Comment: Afraid I got the same with InnerHtml. Maybe my path is wrong? From what I've read, I can go straight to the opening tag I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works if you load your doc from `string`.

if you want to load it from an url use  `doc.Load(url);` not  `doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);`

--EDIT--

Sorry, my bad, `doc.Load` doesn't accept `http`
You can use something like this

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    doc.LoadHtml(wc.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Comment: Hi L.B - doc.Load("http://www.site.com"); results in "URI formats are not supported." Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Stack took out the 'http' part.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML above is missing a closing table tag. Could that be the problem?
You could try Hpricot or Nokogiri.

Comment: Hey rstackhouse - there's actually more to the table. I just wanted you to be able to see what I see when trying to identify it.